# UiTableView number of generated cells

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have two viewControllers. The first with a stepper:

```
var steppers : UIStepper?

@IBOutlet weak var hourLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var stepper: UIStepper!

@IBAction func stepper(_ sender: UIStepper) {
     hourLabel.text = String(sender.value)
}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if let np = segue.destination as? CourseClass2 {
        np.numberPlaces = Int(stepper.value)
    }
}
```

and the second with a tableView:

```
private let resueIdentifier = "MyTableViewCell"

extension UIViewController {
    func present(viewController : UIViewController, completion : (() -> ())? = nil ){
        if let presented = self.presentedViewController {
            presented.dismiss(animated: true, completion: {
                self.present(viewController, animated: true, completion: completion)
            })
        } else {
            self.present(viewController, animated: true, completion: completion)
        }
    }
}

class CourseClass2: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    var locationManager:CLLocationManager?
    let minimumSpacing : CGFloat = 15 //CGFloat(MAXFLOAT)
    let cellWidth: CGFloat = 250
    let radius = 5000 // 5km
    var category : QCategoryy?
    var currentLocation : CLLocationCoordinate2D?
    var places: [QPlace] = []
    var isLoading = false
    var response : QNearbyPlacesResponse?
    var rows = 0
    var numberPlaces = 0

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.title = category?.name
        tableView.dataSource = self
        tableView.delegate = self
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)

        determineMyCurrentLocation()
    }

    override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)

        rows = 0
     /*   insertRowsMode3()
        tableView.reloadData()  */
        category?.markView()
    }

    @IBAction func refreshTapped(_ sender: Any) {
        rows = 0
    /*    insertRowsMode3()  */
        tableView.reloadData()
    }

    func canLoadMore() -> Bool {
        if isLoading {
            return false
        }

        if let response = self.response {
            if (!response.canLoadMore()) {
                return false
            }
        }

        return true
    }

    func loadPlaces(_ force:Bool) {
        if !force {
            if !canLoadMore() {
                return
            }
        }

        print("load more")
        isLoading = true
        NearbyPlaces.getNearbyPlaces(by: category?.name ?? "food", coordinates: currentLocation!, radius: radius, token: self.response?.nextPageToken, completion: didReceiveResponse)
    }

    func didReceiveResponse(response:QNearbyPlacesResponse?, error : Error?) -> Void {
        if let error = error {
            let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Error", message: error.localizedDescription, preferredStyle: .alert)
            let actionDismiss = UIAlertAction(title: "Dismiss", style: .cancel, handler: nil)
            let actionRetry = UIAlertAction(title: "Retry", style: .default, handler: { (action) in
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.loadPlaces(true)
                }
            })
            alertController.addAction(actionRetry)
            alertController.addAction(actionDismiss)
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.present(viewController: alertController)

            }
        }
        if let response = response {
            self.response = response
            if response.status == "OK" {
                if let placesDownloaded = response.places {
                    places.append(contentsOf: placesDownloaded)
                }

               self.tableView?.reloadData()
            } else {
                let alert = UIAlertController.init(title: "Error", message: response.status, preferredStyle: .alert)
                alert.addAction(UIAlertAction.init(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: nil))
                alert.addAction(UIAlertAction.init(title: "Retry", style: .default, handler: { (action) in
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.loadPlaces(true)
                    }
                }))
                 self.present(viewController: alert)
            }
            isLoading = false
        }
        else {
            print("response is nil")
        }
    }

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        print("numberOfsection Call")
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        print("numberOfRows Call")
        return  places.count   /*  rows   */
    }

    public  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: resueIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! MyTableViewCell

        let place = places[indexPath.row]
        cell.update(place: place)

        if indexPath.row == places.count - 1 {
            loadPlaces(false)
        }
        print("CellForRow Call")
        return (cell)
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2, animations: {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "MyTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! MyTableViewCell
    })

        performSegue(withIdentifier: "goToLast" , sender: indexPath.row)
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 100
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
        return true
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyle.delete {
            places.remove(at: indexPath.row)
            tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
        }
    }

    func didReceiveUserLocation(_ userLocation:CLLocation) {
        currentLocation = userLocation.coordinate

        loadPlaces(true)
    }
```

I added only the code useful for the question. As you can see I'm trying to pass from the first VC to the second this value:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if let np = segue.destination as? CourseClass2 {
        np.numberPlaces = Int(stepper.value)
    }
}
```

Because I would like to add a limit to the number of cells that spawn when loading the tableview in the second viewController (and I want this limit to be chosen by the user with the stepper in the previous controller), how do I have to modify the tableView to make sure that the number of cells generated is equal to the value of `var numberPlaces`?

Comment: Are you using the content of `places` as backing for the table view?

Comment: @PhillipMills yes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest that you limit the number of cells inside `UITableView` delegate method number of cells

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    print("numberOfRows Call")
    if places.count < self.numberPlaces {
        return places.count   /*  rows   */
    } 
    return  self.numberPlaces
}
```

In this way, you will get right number of cells, but if there would be too many places only self.numberPlaces will be displayed.

Maybe, you would need to figure out some sorting, so that correct places would be displayed. (By proximity,...)

Comment: i tried but with this change the tableView do not display nothing, anyhow
always the places.count will be higher than numberPlaces

Comment: i only need that the places.count is = to numberPlaces

Comment: pleas, could you confirm that inside this method, you get the right set value self.numberPlaces.

Comment: "always the places.count will be higher than numberPlaces", this is a bad practice, to assume this. I know that for now this might be true, but in the future, with new functionality it might not be. By then, you will forget that you left potentially dangerous code. Try to avoid problems in the future, it is a good practice.

Comment: yes i confirm, i also have to tell that i'm using  the content of "places" as backing for the table view

Comment: Even if you press refresh button? What it is written if you put print("numberOfRows Call", self.numberPlaces) in this method?

Comment: this is my console with one tap of the refresh button (where i added the print) numberOfsection Call
numberOfRows Call
numberOfsection Call
numberOfRows Call
numberOfsection Call
numberOfRows Call
user latitude = 41.844326
user longitude = 12.467619
load more
numberOfsection Call
numberOfRows Call
numberOfRows Call 0
numberOfsection Call
numberOfRows Call

Comment: so numberOfRows Call 0

Comment: and nill before (there is no number). This means that code is working, but your variable is not set. Try with fix number (like 5). Try debugging to see why it is not set

Comment: you are right! the problem is the variable, and it not work because i step  trhough another viewController before arriving in the controller with the tableView, so the first controller is with the stepper and the third is with the tableView